# Passing the value of JSON Object from HTTP Request to another JSON Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, chatbot

I'm working on simple Chatbot in Line Messenger. I found some API which I want to use in the following way:

User sends specific key word like `!send data`. Then I send HTTP Request using request module. I'm getting the response and I output it in the console just to see if everything is correct. I'm parsing the `repsonse` with `JSON.parse(body)` and I'm able to access its specific values with

```
result = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(result.value.text);
```

Now I want to send result.value.text as a reply mesaage to the Line client.
Message has form

```
message = {
  type: "text",
  text: "someString"
}
```

But how can I pass the part of HTTP response to this object? Trying something like this

```
LINEResponse = {
  type: "text",
  text: result.value.text
};
```

leads to

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

I'm not 100% sure if its even correct approach implement this. I would appreciate any help

Comment: What happens if you do a `console.log(LINEResponse)`?

Comment: if possible can you share your request code also ?

Comment: Your question will be difficult to answer without some context. What I can point out is that an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error is being triggered because you didn't catch an error that's being thrown by a function using promises. Anyway, if you can access the value from 'result.value.text' , then you should be able to use it like you're doing in your example. Just try to assign it to a variable to sanity check for any kind of unexpected errors ( maybe you already have declared other vars with that name ):
`var temp = result.value.text; LINEResponse = {type:"text",text:temp};`

Comment: `request('url', function(error, response, body) { 
result = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(result.value.text);
temp = result.value.text;
myMethod(event, temp)`

So this is fixed solution, I created a separate method which builds a message and sends it to the client. Previously I tried to do both at once and it seems it was a problem.